# Pronunciation of 天爾遠波 (てにをは)

Tags: words, pronunciation

Straightforward question.  `天爾遠波` (or `弖爾乎波`) - written as `てにをは` - is a term used to refer to the Japanese particles (`助詞`) or sometimes Japanese grammar as a whole (`文法`).  So how to do pronounce the `は` at the end?  Is it `ワ` or `ハ`?  Presumably it's the former since it's describing particles, but I've never seen it definitively explained anywhere.

Comment: NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典 gives the reading as テニオハ. But see here www.tt.rim.or.jp/~rudyard/hirago013.html
【無論、普通は「てにをは」は「tenioha」と読みます。
この言葉だけを見れば、「は」で問題ないことでしょう。
しかし、「こんにちわ」や「こんばんわ」を支持するなら、それではいけません。】

Comment: Clickable link from above comment:  http://www.tt.rim.or.jp/~rudyard/hirago013.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the entry about は in デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/172789/m0u/):

> 「は」は、平安時代半ば以後、語中・語尾では、一般に［wa］と発音されるようになった。これらは、歴史的仮名遣いでは「は」と書くが、現代仮名遣いでは、助詞「は」以外はすべて「わ」と書く。

Which is probably the source of confusion.  If one thinks of it as a "word" then they might be inclined to read it as `te-ni-o-wa`.

However, according to [the entry about てにをは in デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/152154/m0u/):

> 《ヲコト点の一種の博士家(はかせけ)点の四隅の点を、左下から右回りに続けて読むと「てにをは」となるところから》

So, as you can see, it's more like an acronym of sorts than it is an actual "word" (as in it identifies the markup actually used in `漢文`).  Therefore, it is read as `te-ni-o-ha`.

---

Additionally, `イロハ` (i.e., `伊呂波短歌`) is read as `i-ro-ha` and not `i-ro-wa` (I have no sources to back up this claim, though, other than my own experience).

Comment: +1 for comparing it to `伊呂波`.

Answer (score 0):

The は is being used as the pronunciation of 波, and not as a particle. Thus it is pronounced like a ハ. The particle は is *always* in the hiragana form, so as it is a kanji it must be pronounced ハ.

Just because it is *describing* particles does not mean it *is* a particle.

Remember, if は is the pronunciation of a kanji, it is always pronounced ハ. Only when it is a particle (when it must be in hiragana form) can it pronounced ワ.

Comment: Source?  `難波` (the old name for Osaka) is pronounced `なにわ`, so there's at least one one instance where `波` is not pronounced 'ハ'.

Comment: http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E6%B3%A2

The onyomi reading is listed as ハ.